# A P2P CRM Proposal

Tags: silverlight, synchronization, crm, p2p

At first, I found a P2P CRM on http://www.ajatus.info/. But it was discontinued for years. And it is not natural to have a local web server. And the worst thing is that is hard to integrate its data with other data source for it used CouchDb.

So I draft a P2P CRM proposal and I am thinking to implement it.

Features:

1. Decentralization
2. Free( Free for software, no additional cost for related software)
3. Run Immediately (No installation needed, no configuration needed)
4. Social networking support.
5. Email and Contacts friendly

Basic architecture: 4 independent software.

1,  Personal CRM

A Silverlight CRM application with a built- in SQL CE database. This is a completed package to run and no installation needed any more.

2,  Central CRM

Central server is for performance and to simplify the support, which could be based on a typical SQL Server database of Splendid/Tiger CRM. This is a completed package also.

3,  CRM Bridge

A bridge to synchronize the personal CRM and Central CRM. This will be an open source project for ANY CRM synchronize to the client.  This is to be done by MS Sync Framework. ( MS Live Sync could be a better solution when it is ready and available in XP platform.)

4,  Social Collector

A social data collector to collect all data from social networks and other data source. There is a good project in Codeplex.com (http://semsync.codeplex.com/)  to collect and synchronize all contacts information together.

Scenario:

1. personal only.
2. Client to Central CRM directly (in DB layer).
3. Personal with synchronization to the central.

Any suggestions?

Ying

Comment: In the above, I only mentioned Microsoft databases. But in deed I am thinking to use any Non SQL databases to improve flexibility. You may find a list of Non SQL databases here, http://nosql-database.org/ .

Answer (score 0):

If Java is an option for you, the [JXTA](http://jxse.kenai.com) framework will help you with the P2P features of your application.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but I feel your base analysis is somewhat flawed.

1. "not natural to have a local web server"
   By whose rules? 
   If you are a intenet application vendor (cloud computing hawkers) then they will tell you it is not natural.

The whole thing of P2P is to rethink those values. 
If it makes sense put a web server on the localmachine put it on the local machine
Remember the original vision "The network is the computer";
Not "Large Data Centers are the computer"

2."CouchDB is hard to integrate"! 
I think that is misinformed. 
CouchDB has a RESTful JSON API that makes it about as integratable as you can get. 
What you really mean is Couch doesn't fit into Visual Studio Development System like SQL Server. Which is true but doesn't make it hard to integrate data with other data. 
There are some replication options you might want to look at.

To be honest what you are offering isn't much different than MS CRM with a social plugins module. 
I think it would be difficult to get traction in the OSS Space and your gonna need help for a project that size.